# how to send a real time data to server?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i want to send the base64 image format from live stream webcam to the server. now, i have a base64 image format but i don't know how to send it to the server. this is my code

does anyone can give a solution ? btw i'm using flask as server.

```
var constraints = { audio: false, video: { width: 500, height: 500 } }; 
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

var image = new Object();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); })

function capture() {

  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

  return data;
}

setInterval(function(){
    var imgData = capture();
    image.images = imgData;

    //i want to send the image object to the server
    console.log(image);

}, 1000/100)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [efficient way of streaming a html5 canvas content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256710/efficient-way-of-streaming-a-html5-canvas-content)

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest to send the image. [official](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375635/xhr-send-base64-string-and-decode-it-in-the-server-to-a-file) examples

Comment: What is your server side? U can use SignalR

Comment: i just mention above, my server is using flask python @pc_coder